# What can I use to run the CPU, GPU and GSM radio on simultaneously on Android?

Tags: android, performance-testing

I'd like to run the CPU, GPU and GSM radio on heavy load simultaneouslly, essentially to generate as much heat as possible. 
Is there an app or a diagnostic mode that I can use to make this happen. I have the LG G6.

Answer (score 0):

[Battery Waster - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stdev293.batterywasterdemo)

"It leverages (multi-core) CPU, GPU, camera flash LED, screen brightness, sensors (MEMS and more) and GPS to maximise current consumption." You'll definitely generate heat! You could also be charging at the same time.